# Best Buy Web Crawler forbidden error

Tags: c#, web, web-crawler, webclient

I'm trying to make a crawler for the Best Buy website, however when I try to run the DownloadString function I get a 403 forbidden error.  I've tried adding a header but the results remain the same.  I've also run Fiddler and see what header is being sent by my browser and used the header there.  What could possibly be causing the issue?

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36");
        client.DownloadString("http://www.bestbuy.com");
```

Comment: One of the other headers, maybe? Use wireshark and diff the headers sent by your app and the browser.

Comment: Get a packet capture program, visit the site using your program and a working browser (or `wget`), and compare.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like you spoofing multiple browsers at the same time. Did you try picking just one of them for your user-agent? I've never seen a browser try to identify itself as several different ones from different OSes at the same time; perhaps their server detects this and denies access to prevent web scrapers.

Comment: I tried your code as you have pasted it and it works for me. I don't get a 403.